# FxCop CA2000 Warning in UserControls

Tags: .net, fxcop, servercontrols

Running FxCop on a WebProject that contains a UserControl will result in a CA2000 Warning (Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object) for every ServerControl (Label, TextBox,...) in that UserControl.

I understand why this would happen. 
Replacing the 'offending' ServerControls with a PlaceHolder and then adding the Controls in code (Using...End Using) might be a way around that, but it is not always an option.
But, if they are not 'kosher' why have ServerControls you can drop in your ascx/aspx in the first place ?
Am I missing something ?

If, like in my case, you inherit a sizeable collection of fairly complex UserControls, do I now add every 'offending' Control to the GlobalSupperssions file (that's a lot of mind numbing right-clicking) ?
I do not want to suppress all CA2000 warnings since it makes perfect sense to fix them, but not in the case of ServerControls in UserControls.

Comment: i'm probably missing something, but wouldn't you just override dispose (well, dispose(bool) i guess) and have it dispose the server controls contained in your usercontrol?  the warning seems to make sense if you're not 'cascading' the dispose down the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmya, everybody *really* likes a tool that will tell them that they forgot to call Dispose().  Problem is: such a tool is really hard to implement.  The specific warning you are talking about got disabled and re-enabled a few times now.

Obviously the warning you got is nonsense, a UserControl already knows how to properly dispose its member controls.  It is just not something that an automated tool can easily detect.  The dispose call is a million miles removed from the constructor call, buried in .NET framework code with a couple of virtual methods and event handlers thrown in the mix.

To *really* evaluate those warnings, you'll have to switch to another tool: the one between your ears.

Comment: Thanks, you pretty much confirm what was between my ear, which I guess is what I needed.